# Creating separate columns based on string value in python

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am quite new but I am working with a dataframe that looks like the below:

```
ID       Tag  
123      Asset Class > Equity  
123      Inquiry Type > Demonstration
123      Inquiry Topic > Holdings  
456      Asset Class > Fixed Income  
456      Inquiry Type > BF   
456      Inquiry Topic > VaR
```

What I am trying to do is change this into a dataframe which looks like the below:

```
ID       Asset Type      Inquiry Type      Inquiry Topic  
123      Equity          Demonstration     Holdings
456      Fixed Income    Bf                VaR
```

Sorry if this is quite simple; however, I am having an issue with this manipulation. I have tried .melt but this does not seem to complete what I am trying to complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot.html) and selecting splitted lists by indexing:

```
s = df['Tag'].str.split(' > ')
df = (pd.pivot(index=df['ID'], columns=s.str[0], values=s.str[1])
       .reset_index()
       .rename_axis(None, 1))
print (df)
    ID   Asset Class Inquiry Topic   Inquiry Type
0  123        Equity      Holdings  Demonstration
1  456  Fixed Income           VaR             BF
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!